# ReferenceError: process is not defined in angular v16

Tags: angular

I installed "@types/node" and added "types": ["node"] to "compilerOptions" inside "tsconfig.app.json" as you are supposed to when trying to reference the "process" variable.

But once executed I get an error in the browser: "ReferenceError: process is not defined".

I just tried to use my package.json version via

```
appVersion = process.env['npm_package_version'];
```

All other suggestions on the web such as adding

```
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

to polyfill.js are outdated... angular 16 does not have a polyfill.js anymore...

While adding

```
    <script>
      var process = process || {
        env: { DEBUG: undefined },
        version: [],
      };
    </script>
```

to the  of my index.html file did not cause any errors the referenced version was just missing (empty text string)

What's the approach with angular v16+?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue with angular 17

Answer (score -1):

Angular is run in the browser, not in an nodejs runtime. You can't access NodeJS runtime variables like `process`.

Also, there is no straightforward solution to retrieve the app version from the `package.json` without exposing the `package.json`.